# Laravel 4.2 Help Needed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

I have this piece of code in my HomeController.php which is within the public function home() block

```
//Fetch Users Online
$online = DB::table('users')->where('online','1')->get(); 

//Get All Users Online Count
$num_online = DB::table('users')->where('online','1')->count();

//Get All ADMIN Online Count
$admin_online = DB::table('users')->where('online','1')->where('group_id','4')->count();

//Get All MODS Online Count
$mod_online = DB::table('users')->where('online','1')->where('group_id','6')->count();

//Get All VIP Online Count
$vip_online = DB::table('users')->where('online','1')->where('group_id','8')->count();

//Get All UPLOADER Online Count
$uploader_online = DB::table('users')->where('online','1')->where('group_id','7')->count();

//Get All MEMBERS Online Count
$member_online = DB::table('users')->where('online','1')->where('group_id','3')->count();
```

which is relayed in the home.blade.php here

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h4>Online Users <span class="badge">{{ $num_online }}</span></h4></div>
<div class="panel-body">
@foreach($online as $o)
<span class="badge-user group-member">
{{ $o->username }}
</span>
@endforeach
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<span class="badge-user group-member">Member ({{ $member_online }})</span> <span class="badge-user group-uploader">Uploader ({{ $uploader_online }})</span> <span class="badge-user group-vip">VIP ({{ $vip_online }})</span> <span class="badge-user group-staff">Mod ({{ $mod_online }})</span> <span class="badge-user group-su">Admin ({{ $admin_online }})</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /Online Users -->
```

My question is in my users table in my DB i have the online column called online. 0 is offline and 1 is online. If a manually update a users Online status from a zero to a one then they show up in the ONLINE block shown above as they should. But how can I automate this? If a user logs in its set to 1 and if they logout its set to 0.

any help would be appreciated.....

Im running laravel 4.2 and guessing this would be easier to accomplish in 5.4
Im dreading upgrading and don't even want to attempt it on my own.

Comment: You'll have an issue with users who *don't* log out. Either use websockets for this, or every time a user does something on the site update a record to store their last activity date, and treat them as "online" if they've done something in the last 5-10 minutes or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by creating and listening to events.

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    $user->online = 1;

    $user->save();
});

Event::listen('auth.logout', function($user)
{
    $user->online = 0;

    $user->save();
});
```

Please follow [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events) for detailed information

Answer (score 0):

You can check at the user sessions, when you use the database driver for sessions there will be a column called `last_activity`, if the user hasn't done anything in 15 mins you know it is offline.

You can't depend on if a user logs out. Not everyone does that every time.